# One can define lateral derivative for a discontinuous point?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

This doubt is very simple, but I am stucked with an exercise proposed to a class. There is a function $f$ discontinuous in $P$ e there are laws for $x>P$ and $x\leq P$. Lateral derivatives are requested for $ P $.

I haven't studied basic calculus for a long time, but I thought I never saw the definition of lateral derivatives applied to points of discontinuity. Can I use the traditional limit $\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$? Or that would be a mistake of the question?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $x \to x_0 ^+ \, , \, h \to 0^+$ as right deriv. and $x \to x_0 ^-  \,  , \,h \to 0^-$ as left

Comment: They can exist (but not always) if you allow for infinite derivatives (i.e. allow the answer to be $+\infty$ or $-\infty).$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, yes, in this case $-\infty$ is the solution of the limit... But I am thinking if there's some definition for this, ie, if there exists the definition of lateral derivative without the continuity hypotesis, what do you think?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. It's easy to see that, in the limit at a point of discontinuity, the difference quotients become unbounded. Now it's possible that the unboundedness is restricted to one side only, and if so, it's additionally possible that the difference quotients on that side converge, so you can get a finite one-sided derivative on such a side. The greatest integer function, for example, has zero right-hand derivatives at every integer. But, if the function is discontinuous at a point, at least one side CANNOT have a finite limit of the difference quotients at that point.

Comment: Thank you @DaveL.Renfro